# PHP GD imagepng function showing up as garbled text

Tags: php, mamp, php-gd

I am reading a book and followed one of the tutorials.  After following the tutorial to the letter the program does not work as expected.

I found a similar but much simpler tutorial online and found that it does the same thing on my system. I am using a macintosh and running MAMP for the local server if that helps debug anything...

Please check out the code I was using to try and make a .png with PHP

```
     <?php
       // error_reporting(E_ALL);
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        $png_image = imagecreate(150, 150);
        imagecolorallocate($png_image, 15, 142, 210);
        imagepng($png_image);
         imagedestroy($png_image);
      ?>
```

This does not throw any errors, even when un-commenting the error_reporting function and commenting out the header function.

This is what I see when running this script.

```
    ‰PNG  IHDR––Ïã¡PLTEŽÒaû|ÚIDATH‰íÁ1Â õOm  €w¸¡l‡qIEND®B`‚
```

Comment: Run unchanged on my development server gives a blue square, just as I would expect.

Comment: weird, I looked at php.ini and it shows that this GD thing is enabled or whatever

Comment: `GD Support  enabled`
`GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible) `

Comment: interesting. thanks for the feedback. :D

Comment: Looks like you are outputting whitespace before the `header`. Turn you error reporting on `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: I receive this error with your suggestions `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ch11/image.php:1) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ch11/image.php on line 4
‰PNG  IHDR––Ïã¡PLTEŽÒaû|ÚIDATH‰íÁ1Â õOm  €w¸¡l‡qIEND®B\`‚`

Comment: Looks like this is just a warning though...also if I call this script from another page with an HTML IMG tag it still does not work. That code is like `<img src="image.php" />` I also tried changing the code to create a JPEG and it still does not work. I found a similar issue on stackoverflow but my problem is different I think.